# Remote Control of Prosody Server

Tags: xmpp, prosody-im

I am setting up an XMPP server that can be used to send real-time messages to clients as directed by a central application. I want the clients to be as simple as possible, so I want the server to handle account creation and destruction.

I think Prosody is probably the server I will use. I have set it up in a Docker image and can perform all basic functionality, but I haven't figured out the best way to administer it remotely. I'd like the following two functions exposed to an authenticated user (over XMPP or HTTP):

- create user
- delete user

I have considered setting up a Python `SimpleHTTPServer` instance, but this breaks the Docker model of running each app in a standalone container. I *could* have multiple containers and communicate data back and forth between them, but that's starting to add layers of complexity that feel like overkill.

Does anyone know of an easy way to monitor and manage a Prosody (or other) XMPP server over HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

I love it to answer questions after years.

I am not sure what you want to do but at least what concerns prosody you can use **prosodyctl** on command line level. So you could design your HTTP Interface to use the **prosodyctl** from command line level.

```
prosodyctl adduser JID
```

and

```
prosodyctl deluser JID
```

depending how you design your http interface (with cgi, or php ) you can use a diversity of commands to execute the commands via shell and return the complete output as a string.

But I suppose this is not subject of the question.